# Visual Studio "Solution explorer" disappearing shortcut key?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

Yes, I'd like to know how to kill it.
(For displaying, I know "Ctrl w s")

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift + Escape should close it, if it has the focus. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#bkmk_window) for the window shortcuts.

There is nothing listed under [Solution Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#bkmk_solutionexplorerGLOBAL) itself that would close it.

Comment: Thanks... Hmm.. That's a kind of answer. Because I did not mentioned the focus. I'm looking forward to find focus_less shortcut key. I'll check out MSDN as you mentioned.